# How I can update key of Laravel cache?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis

i store some id in cache like this :

```
$ids = Cache::remember('customer', 120, function () {
        return [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    });
```

how can remove `1 and  2` from cache?

Comment: cache again without `1` `2`

Comment: @sta  no other way?

Comment: all you need is to cache it again. No other way based on your test case.

Comment: Cache::put('key', 'value', 0);  u can use cache like this

Answer (score 0):

In your case when you call `Cache::remember`, laravel will store the array `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` as a serialized string. So in your case if you want to remove `1,2`, you have to call `Cache::remember` again.

If you want to store an array and remove some value inside, you'd better use redis instead,in redis command you can use `SADD` to store values like `SADD customer 1 2 3 4`.And remove values with `SREM customer 1 2`.And get all with `SMEMBERS customer`.You can use it in php with [predis](https://github.com/predis/predis)